# Interface for POCO to test with Moq

Tags: c#, oop, interface, moq

We have a class with just properties, a method to test that doesn't return anything and we are using Moq to emulate its dependencies. We wanted to test if some property of the object is set. So we tried to mock the class so later we would use the VerifySet method from Moq, it complains as the property is not marked as virtual nor it is an interface. Creating an interface works and we can verify the property as needed. Should we create an interface for everything, including cases like this, a POCO?

Below I include a minimal example but the actual code is considerable bigger.

Class

```
public class Car
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Test

```
var mock = Mock<ICar>();

handler.Handle(mock);

mock.VerifySet(x=> x.Name = "Furioso");
```

Method

```
public void Handle(Car car)
{
    car.Name = "Furioso"
}
```

Interface

```
public interface ICar
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Personally I think you are testing the wrong thing here. This to me looks like you need to re think your testing (sorry I know its not really an answer)

Comment: The class that you are testing is not supposed to be mocked. The dependencies of the class (if any) are mocked. If you do this, whatever properties that are set in that class, you can check after you run whatever method you are testing, in the assertion step. You don't mock POCOs.

Comment: @insane_developer then, without mocking Car, how would you assert that it was modified as expected if the method returns void?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me that you want to `assert` changes rather then checking if the `setter` has been called.

Really think about what you're trying to test here for example lets say you have a `service` that changes certain properties.

```
public class MyValue {
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class MyService {
    
    public void ChangeValues(MyValue value, string toValue) {
    
        value.Value = toValue;
    }
}
```

What if the service looked like this:

```
public class MyService {
    
    public void ChangeValues(MyValue value, string toValue) {
    
        value.Value = "toValue";
    }
}
```

When testing if the `setter` has been called both situations will assert to true.

When you assert the changes made to `value.Value` only the first situation will succeed.

Comment: I'm unsure if I understood this part "When you assert the changes made to value.Value only the first situation will succeed." I understood that I should assert the new value instead of just if the property was set. I'm actually doing that using the interface so I updated the code example to reflect that. The problem is that if I follow that approach I would be creating interfaces for POCOs and I wonder if it is correct to do so or if there are alternatives in order to verify the change as you suggest and I agree.

Comment: With first situation i ment the first code block where `value.Value` is set with the property value given as parameter (`toValue`). The second code block has faulty code and will not represent the value of parameter `toValue`. If you want to verify the change made to a POCO create an instance of the object before calling the method and verify the changes after calling the method. POCO's are ment to be plain and simple, i wouldn't recommend creating interfaces for them. Just instantiate the POCO.

Answer (score 3):

I am making assumptions here, but this is what I'm trying to convey:

```
var car = new Car(); //no behavior to mock here, just a DTO. You may have to set values to this instance before passing it (or not).

handler.Handle(car); //handler is the instance of the class being tested

//Any other assertions
Assert.Equal("Furioso", car.Name); //I don't use Moq, but whatever is equivalent.
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer, and the selected one, helped me to remember some concepts and solve the problem.